# Display resolution for Dell Monitor gone after update

Tags: dell, display, display-resolution

After updating my Ubuntu 14.04 software today, my display properties stopped recognizing the Dell monitor I'm using.

I'm stuck at 1024x768 whereas this morning I had options to go to the rull resolution of my monitor.

[image]

Graphics card info was found using the following command...

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

With the following output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
```

Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a Nvidia or ATI graphics card?

Comment: @AlexSpataru I updated my question with the output from a command-line prompt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the **firmware-addon-dell** plugin via Synaptic Package Manager, and I now have the full details of the Dell Monitor in my display properties:

[image]

...and the display properties:

[image]

This update, as referred to in the original question above, has been the first trigger in several years of using Ubuntu with this Dell monitor, that I have needed to install any Dell firmware. Not sure if that's a valuable tidbit...!